# How to adjust SELinux to allow not so large file downloads in Apache?

Tags: apache-2.4, centos7, selinux

I have a centos 7 server running Apache 2.4 that will happily allow users to download files until they get to a certain size.  I've noticed the problem with mp4 video files; I host both low and full resolution files on the site.  The low res files are usually less than 5 MB but the full res files can exceed 30 MB.  The same script processes and copies them to the website and I can verify all the file permissions are the same.  If I change SELinux to setenforce=0 the files will download without issue.  While SELinux is enforcing, apache returns a Forbidden error instead.

Any thoughts on what SELinux policy I need to adjust?

Comment: Look into using audit2allow to see what recommendations it has - it analyzes the actual failures in the audit log to suggest a fix.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the suggestion to use audit2allow, tilleyc.  It turns out the video file was 'mislabeled' on my system and the base type was listed as an 'unlabeld_t'.  After using the restorecon command, the files were accessible through the webserver.  I'll have to do a little more testing to see why the error initially happened but audit2allow pointed me in the right direction.  Thanks!

Comment: I'm going with the idea here that when the file is below a certain file size, it is stored in memory. At a certain limit, the file upload code switches to storing the data in a tmp file on disk somewhere -- this is where it gets mislabeled.